# Fitting text within a TextView that has variable height

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

In a RelativeLayout, I have an ImageView and a TextView.

- ImageView's height is set to wrap_contents and width is to fill_parent.
- ImageView is dynamically loaded so image height eventually, the ImageView height as well.
- TextView is aligned below ImageView with width to fill_parent and height set to fill_parent.
- TextView is aligned to Parent bottom.
- TextView's ellipsize is set to end.

When I set longer piece of text for TextView,, the text seem to be running off the screen without any ellipse visible whereas I expect only as much text to be visible as much space available and then have ellipses appear.

Is that something achievable?

Please also note that I cannot set max lines as well because I don't know what is the available height of the TextView and how many lines would fit in there unless ImageView's image is loaded via HTTP call in a background thread.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/loadingpic" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/excerpt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/heading"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elipsize property only work when set maxLine or singleLine true.
Please try to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
  android:scrollHorizontally = "true"
```

See: [How to Add an ellipsis(...) in a TextView](http://androidsbs.blogspot.com/2013/11/add-ellipsis-in-textview.html)